Changing sql queries in loop using variables and SED command in bash
I have a script in bash I want to replace some variables and also use SED command on top of it.
while IFS= read -r job_name;
do
job_id="$(echo $job_name | cut -c2-5)"
job_set_id="$(echo $job_name | cut -d '_' -f 1)"

sed -i 's/++++TABLE_NAME++++/'${table_name}'/g' | 
echo "
INSERT INTO ++++TABLE_NAME++++
SELECT '$job_id' as job_id, '$job_set_id' as job_set_id from
++++SOURCE_TABLE_NAME+++++;" >>final_output.txt
done < abc.txt

contents of abc.txt
p1234_job_run
p2345_job_run

expected out in final_output.txt file is below
INSERT INTO ${table_name}
SELECT '1234' as job_id, 'p1234' as job_set_id from
${source_table_name}

INSERT INTO ${table_name}
SELECT '2345' as job_id, 'p2345' as job_set_id from
${source_table_name}

output I am getting is below
INSERT INTO ++++TABLE_NAME++++
SELECT '1234' as job_id, 'p1234' as job_set_id from
++++SOURCE_TABLE_NAME+++++;

INSERT INTO ++++TABLE_NAME++++
SELECT '2345' as job_id, 'p2345' as job_set_id from
++++SOURCE_TABLE_NAME+++++;

I have tried changing the script like below
while IFS= read -r job_name;
do
job_id="$(echo $job_name | cut -c2-5)"
job_set_id="$(echo $job_name | cut -d '_' -f 1)"


echo "
INSERT INTO ++++TABLE_NAME++++
SELECT '$job_id' as job_id, '$job_set_id' as job_set_id from
++++SOURCE_TABLE_NAME+++++;" |  sed -i 's/++++TABLE_NAME++++/'${table_name}'/g' >>final_output.txt
done < abc.txt  
    

I am getting below error
sed: no input files

What wrong I am doing and what is the correct method to achieve my result

Don''t use -i!

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub where should I place the SED command using my changed script or original script

Why did you use sed at all? You could echo "INSERT INTO ${table_name}"....

Where is content of ${table_name}?

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub It is empty variable.

sed -i is for updating a file in place. If you're writing the result to a new file, you don't use it. That's why you get "no input files".

You have two different "expected output" in your question. Which is the one you actually want?

@Barmar Updated the output

You can use the shell's word splitting to get the job set ID from the input file, and parameter expansion to get the job ID from that.
Then you can substitute those variables into a here-doc to write to the output file.
Escape the $ in ${table_name} and ${source_table_name} to write them literally into the output file.
while IFS=_ read job_set_id _; do
    job_id=${job_set_id:1}
    cat <<EOF
INSERT INTO \${table_name}
SELECT '$job_id' as job_id, '$job_set_id' as job_set_id from
\${source_table_name};

<<EOF
done < abc.txt > final_output.txt

